# my website under attack, how to stop this

Tags: sql-server, security

my website seems to be under attack.  i found this in one of the logs:

> 2014-12-23 01:37:35 46.148.31.54 - x.x.x.x 80 GET
>   /pagename.asp?fieldname=558211'+declare+@s+varchar(8000)+set+@s=cast(0x73657420616e73695f7761726e696e6773206f6666204445434c4152452040(...long
>   hex
>   code...)6f72+as+varchar(8000))+exec(@s)--|44|80040e07|Syntax_error_converting_the_varchar_value_'558211_declare_@s_varchar(8000)*set*@scast(0x73657420616e73695f7761(...long
>   hex code...)e636f... 500
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_8_5)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/38.0.2125.104+Safari/537.36

I tried some online hex to string converter and it shows that all that hex is actually a sql statement meant to put a website link in all table columns.  it uses information_schema thing
now I am very inexperienced, but this looks like some sql injection attack.  i use simple things like filtering characters etc. 
But I wish to know how to stop this kind of attack when sql statement is converted to hex and then used in urls.  i searched around but couldn't find anything to prevent this particular type to attempt.
thank you for your time

Comment: Use parameterized queries and you should be safe from SQL injection.

Comment: Sanitize your parameters before passing them to query.

Answer (score 2):

what you've got there is an SQL injection attack.
take your website down before they download your entire database.
find the flaws (here handling of the `fieldname` query parameter) and fix them.
then put your website back up.  also turn off detailed error messages from the database from going to the general public.

Merry Christmas!